# Are there any suggested names to name a baby?

Tags: naming, baby

My son will be born in around 40 days (insha’allah).
 I was wondering has the Prophet (peace be upon him and his household) suggested/recommended any names to name the new born?
 *If so please provide the ahadeeth.*

Comment: I think you are free to name your baby what ever name you like. you don't have to only choose or think about an Islamic name. There are so many non-Islamic  meaningful names. I think it's totally depends on your and your wife's wish. In my opinion, you should think about a meaningful name instead either it'll be Islamic or not.

Comment: Although you might have had named your baby by now, I support above suggestion of Azad, although Abd-Allah(and other names of Allah) are highly advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> خير الأسماء ماحُمّد وعُبّد

```
Best names which is prefixed by Mohammad or Abed
```

This hadeeth shows the best names to give:

For example:

> AbdoLLAH
>
> Abdurahman
>
> AbduLmalek
>
> Mohamad
>
> Mohamad Ali
>
> Mohamad Hasan
>
> etc....

Answer (score 4):

Best names, according to hadith are Abdullah and Abdur-rehman

Prophet Muhammad said:

> "Keep the names of the Noble Prophets,(Sallallaho alaihe Wasallam)
>   Allah, the Exalted, loves most the names Abdullah and Abdur Rahman. "

Here is more detail about this issue:

http://www.islamcan.com/names/names-that-are-preferred-and-that-are-undesirable..shtml